# Is LdapConnection secure to autenticate user in ActiveDirectory?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have build this function to verify if user is enable in an ActiveDirectory.

**The data transmitted by `LdapConnection` is encrypted ?**

Is this a secure solution to transmit information with `user` and `password` ?

```
try
{
    LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(server);

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
    connection.Credential = credential;

    connection.Bind();
}
catch (LdapException lexc)
{
   return lexc.Message;
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
   return exc.Message;
}
```

Comment: I hope your password is of type [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx). By the way, I don't see anywhere the code related to enabling user in AD! Would you please rephrase your question to highlight what exactly you require? What sort of data transmitted by LdapConnection class are you talking about? Quoting from MSDN: `The LdapConnection class creates a TCP/IP or UDP LDAP connection to Microsoft Active Directory Domain Services or an LDAP server.`.

Comment: User e Password are SecureString. I ask if the transmitted data are encrypted on the Ldap channel. @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: Take a look at http://pdhewaju.com.np/2017/03/02/configuring-secure-ldap-connection-server-2016/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default, no.

Active Directory works on several ports, which performs related functions:

1. 389: LDAP (single domain only) - this is the default
2. 636: LDAP over SSL
3. 3268: Global Catalog (your AD forest)
4. 3269: Global Catalog over SSL

Additional information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875824.aspx

So to make it use an encrypted connection, you need to tell it to use port 636 or 3269, and then tell it to use SSL, like this:

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection($"{server}:636");
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer=true;
```

A warning: In my experience, you can run into problems making this connection because, by default, the domain controllers use a self-signed certificate for the encryption, which your client computer may not trust. If you run into that problem, you can install that certificate on your computer to make it trusted.

But keep in mind that certificates serve two purposes:

1. Encrypt the data in transfer, and
2. Ensure the server you are talking to is actually the server you want to be talking to

1 will always happen with any certificate (even self-signed). #2 is why the connection fails if the certificate is issued by an untrusted source.

If you feel confident you don't need the certificate for purpose #2, then you can tell it to ignore errors related to untrusted certificates, like this:

```
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate =
            new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
```